# Fatal error: Call to undefined function nusoap_client()

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I'm trying to consume a soap web service using `nusoap` and PHP 5.6.25 but I am having some errors. Here is the php code:

```
    require_once 'nusoap-0.9.5/lib/nusoap.php';
    $client = new nusoap_client('http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx?WSDL');
    if($client->getError()){
        echo 'Error';
    } else {
        echo 'nusoap is working';
    }
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function nusoap_client()

Comment: Tell us about the error you get.

Comment: have you heard of the **new**-keyword to instanciate objects?

Comment: "Having some errors" Wouldn't you find it important to include those errors in the question?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I forgot the **new**

Comment: Removed some pleadings.

Comment: if this error persists even after you put the new in place, I would think you may have a path error for the `require_once`  line. `undefined function` means that the library function is not present

Answer (score 0):

If you check any example on the internet about `nusoap_client` you can see that it looks like this:

```
$client = new nusoap_client("food.wsdl", true);
$error  = $client->getError();
```

So when you create a new instances of class `nusoap_client` you need to add the word `new` before. So your code will look like this:

```
$client = new nusoap_client('http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx?WSDL');
if($client->getError()){
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    echo 'nusoap is working';
}
```

Comment: Thanks You Daniel, I really forgot to use **new** keyword.